# How to create common chunks for a group of entry-points in webpack 4?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, next.js

I have a Nextjs app that its pages are separated between 3 regions, admin area, front area, members area.

I want to create a commons chunk for all the `node_modules` packages that are consumed by pages (they are defined as entry points in webpack) that belongs to the same area.

For example this is the folder structure of the project, nextjs configuring each page to be an entry point for webpack.

```
pages/
  admin/
    page-1.jsx
    page-2.jsx
    page-3.jsx
    page-4.jsx
  front/
    page-a.jsx
    page-b.jsx
    page-c.jsx
  members/
    page-a1.jsx
    page-b2.jsx
```

I want to create `admins-common` chunk that will hold all the common `node_module` packages that `page-1`, `page-2`, `page-3`, `page-4` has in common.

If the same package is been used by multiple "groups" (such as react) it would be great if it will be in a `global-commons` chunk.

Hope this is make sense, any points will help.

Comment: how did you go about it? I am in the same situation as you were. any help would be appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: Currently I'm creating chunks manually, by hand picking each lib...this won't scale, this a temp solution till I will split the into 3 separate parts

Comment: It could help to put your `webpack.config` in the post